# Wordpress Multiple loops on category template duplicate posts.

Tags: wordpress, post, duplicates

I have three loops on category.php the first is pulling the most recent single post and the second two loops are filtering the posts into odd and even order to display in columns.

All is working perfectly apart from that the first post in duplicated in the second loop.

I have tried every method I know to stop duplicated posts but I'm stuck on this one.

Loop one:

```
        <?php $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => 1, ); global $wp_query; $duplicate = 0; $the_query = new WP_Query( array_merge( $wp_query->query, $args )  ); while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Loop Two:

```
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : $i++; if(($i % 2) !== 0) : $duplicate = 0; $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

    <?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Loop Three:

```
        <?php $i = 0; rewind_posts(); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : $i++; if(($i % 2) == 0) : $duplicate = 0; $wp_query->next_post(); else : the_post(); if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

    <?php endif; endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reset your loop query with `wp_reset_query();`

ex.

```
<?php
query_posts( 'posts_per_page=5' );
if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        ?><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a><br /><?php
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Tried reset the query but still have no luck,

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the end of Loop 1.

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Then ensure the $post->ID of the post in Loop 1 is also included in $do_not_duplicate.